# Smoothing flat edges

Tags: modeling, edges, smooth

I need help, probably a trivial question, but I can't figure it out. How to round selected edges? (as in the screenshot)[image]

Comment: You could bevel all these edges but it will add geometry which you may not want: https://zupimages.net/up/23/35/56wi.gif